# Is it possible to include dependencies dynamically at run time?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a unique app that needs to be built for different Android platforms (smartphone / tablet and credit card machines). In one of these card machines there is a .aar dependence built on top of the NDK and its alteration is beyond my competence. When I import this dependency into the gradle and install the apk on a device that is not the specific one that uses such a .aar feature, the app crashes.

```
dependencies {

...

    // Pax
    implementation files('libs/NeptuneLiteApi_V2.04.00_20180329.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PPCompAndroid-v1.32.aar') //This dependency is what makes the app crash =/

    // NewLand
    implementation files('libs/libposdigital-1.5.1-4-release.aar')

    // Zoop
    implementation files('libs/zoop-emv-connect-pax-a920-pos_0.10.jar')

...

}
```

I can identify the device using "Build.MODEL" in the runtime code and use the correct SDK for each type of device.

My question is: Can I include this dependency .aar in exception time in the code instead of including it in the gradle as we traditionally do?

Comment: it can't be runtime, it can be compile time using gradle scripts you can do i guess.

Comment: I've already made a switch case based on the applicationId, where the lib was included in the gradle if the applicationId contained a substring. But in this new version I cannot depend on the applicationId.

Comment: Use flavor for gradle